# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion divide one project to two projects

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I got currently the error message above and everything what I've tested, didn't help.

My program is running correctly yesterday. Today I want to divide that project into two parts. One should be the database layer (because it should be used by multiple projects, called from now on `dataProj`), second one is the GUI (called from now on `GUIProj`).

As I do it normally, I wrote now into guiProj under `Project -> Propterties -> Java Build Path -> Projects` the new relation to `dataProj`.

The same thing I did in my tomcat, in that way:
"`Tomcat -> Add and Remove...`" Publish `guiProj`
"`Tomcat -> Open -> Open launch configuration -> Classpath`" add `dataProj`

Because of failure, I wrote now into both (`GUIProj and dataProj`) pom.xml that information:

guiProj pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.test.multi</groupId>
    <artifactId>guiProj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>my testproject</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.test.multi</groupId>
        <artifactId>dataProj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    ...
    <dependencies>
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

dataProj pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.test.multi</groupId>
    <artifactId>dataProj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>my data project</name>
    ...
    <dependencies>
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I start now localhost:8080/`guiProj` the GUI comes up, without any issues. At the moment where I want to use a class of `dataProj` I got this error:

```
 WARNUNG: #{login.loginControl}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
        javax.faces.FacesException: #{login.loginControl}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        ... 27 more
```

Does anybody got an idea, why that failure comes up? If you need more information, please tell me.

I checked now multiple answers regarding to that topic, but nothing of that solution worked for myself.

Thanks a lot, for your help.

Best regards
Björn

Explaination because of duplicate:
I didn't think that it's a duplicate, related to the posting, which was marked here. Because maven load that libraries for myself and not like it is in the linked posting, where the hibernate libraries are missing. The projects is configured in Deployment Assembly that the jars are placed in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score -1):

You need a dependency between your `guiProj` and your `dataProj` so that your `guiProj` can actually use your `dataProj`

Here's an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.gouv.finances.douane.gun.edop</groupId>
  <artifactId>check-dau-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <war.finalName>checkDAU</war.finalName>
  </properties>

...
```

Also I suggest you to make you project modular.

Here's a good documentation to do it : http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for your fast response, I edited my project in that way, what you told me. I do a maven update to both projects and try to publish it again to my tomcat. Short: it didn't worked well :/ do you have more informations for myself? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. You should follow the documentation about Maven multi-module project. Your project is cleary modular since you have "gui" and "data".